# how to create a two column table for differentiating?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to compare two types of networks.

I have 4 comparison points.

How should I create a 2 column table where every of those 4 points for both networks is aligned?

Comment: Could you please add an example of the text you need to be tabulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\toprule
                    &Network A  & Network B\\\midrule
Signal      &Strong         & Weak\\
Noise       &Low                & High\\
Cost            &High               & Low\\
Capacity    &Medium         & High\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

In  your  input file, you usually do as follows to horizontally center the table,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for getting dummy texts
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
Some text goes here\ldots
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{lm{\dimexpr\linewidth/3\relax}c}\toprule
                    &Network A  & Network B\\\midrule
Signal      &Strong         & Weak\\
Noise       &Low                & High\\
Cost            &\lipsum[1]             & Low\\
Capacity    &Medium         & High\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\caption{Network A versus Network B}
\label{table:Comparison-A-vs-B}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]Another text goes here\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: if the point is long, then the text goes out of the page...

Comment: @user494461: see my edit. use `longtable` instead.

Comment: still it goes out...why doesnt the extra text simply move to the next line

Comment: @user494461: use `\m{4cm}`, for example, instead of `c`,`l`, or `r`. See my edit. I have to go for teaching! Bye bye!